# RTAB-MAP with xtion, rplidar, turtelbot (how to utilize lidar internally)

Tags: lidar, turtlebot, cartographer, xtion, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have question about building 3D map with RTAB-MAP and lidar.

As far as I know, RTAB-MAP is SLAM based on image-features and performs loop closure using features.

3D mapping on RTAB-MAP with turtlebot, xtion is good.

But, my robot has additionally lidar and I want to utilize lidar.

I read the questions about build 3d map.

I think that my situation is similar below.

https://answers.ros.org/question/239646/build-a-map-with-husky-laser-and-kinectrealsense/

https://answers.ros.org/question/239823/build-a-map-with-rtabmap-realsense-sick-and-imu-with-sensor-fusion/

https://answers.ros.org/question/242263/3d-map-with-rtab-sick-imu-and-husky-a200/

My questions are below.

1. How do you use additional lidar internally in RTAB-MAP?

1-1.For improving quality of map, how to use lidar in RTAB-MAP?

2. I think this system for utilizing lidar and improving quality of map.

I wonder my method is good or not.

I think below system is using all sensors, so it can make good 3D map.

This link is system image I thought.
[link text](https://drive.google.com/open?id=127KODGj06AaN9fsNUvXF7YlghVunMSEO)

Thank you for reading questions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276873/rtab-map-with-xtion,-rplidar,-turtelbot-(how-to-utilize-lidar-internally)/) by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on this [example](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry_.2B-_2D_laser), here is how to add lidar to rtabmap:

```
<node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
   ...
   <remap from="scan" to="/base_scan"/>
   <param name="subscribe_scan" type="bool" value="true"/>
   <param name="RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining" type="string" value="true"/> <!-- Odometry correction -->
   <param name="Reg/Strategy"              type="string" value="1"/>    <!-- 1=ICP -->
   <param name="Reg/Force3DoF"             type="string" value="true"/> <!-- 2d slam -->
</node>
```

Make sure TF of camera and lidar are correctly set, so that 3D point clouds match with the 2D scans.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on 2017-12-01**:
Hi
Thank you for answer.
I checked TF and build map.

I wonder that lidar is used for correction pose or not.

[http://128.134.57.131/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/스크린샷-2017-12-01-17-19-12.png](http://128.134.57.131/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7-2017-12-01-17-19-12.png)

[http://128.134.57.131/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/스크린샷-2017-12-01-17-19-59.png](http://128.134.57.131/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7-2017-12-01-17-19-59.png)

Thank you.

**Comment by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on 2017-12-01**:
You said "Make sure TF of camera and lidar are correctly set, so that 3D point clouds match with the 2D scans."

this means that 2d scans is used for matching 3D point clouds and quality of 3D map is better than without lidar??

I want to know quality of SLAM depends on only RGB-D, image features.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-12-01**:
With parameter "Reg/Strategy" set to 1 (ICP), scans are used to refine loop closure detections and for odometry correction (when "RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining" is true). In my example, lidar is used to refine the pose, e.g., the 3D clouds are added to poses refined by lidar.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-12-01**:
In your screenshots, the TF between lidar and camera seems ok, as the lidar scans (cyan points) are aligned with their corresponding clouds created from the camera.

**Comment by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on 2017-12-03**:
Thank you for your answer.

I got what you said.

As you said, I measure and set TF.

Below link is TF of my robot.

[link text](http://128.134.57.131/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/save_TF.png)